# Lie groupoid $G$ extensions and principal $\text{Out}(G)$ bundles over Lie groupoids

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, gerbes, differentiable-stacks

I am reading the paper [Non abelian differentiable gerbes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870808003204) by C. Laurent-Gengoux et.al.

The definition $3.4$ of the paper goes as follows:

> Definition : Let $X_1\xrightarrow{\phi} Y_1\rightrightarrows M$ be a Lie groupoid $G$-extension with kernel $\mathcal{K}$. Then $\text{Out}(\mathcal{K},G)\rightarrow M$, considered as an $\text{Out}(G)$-torsor (principal bundle) over the Lie groupoid $[Y\rightrightarrows M]$, is called the **band** of the $G$-extension $\phi$.

Question : Fix a Lie group $G$ and a Lie groupoid $[Y_1\rightrightarrows M]$. Suppose $P\rightarrow M$ is a principal $\text{Out}(G)$-bundle over the Lie groupoid $[Y_1\rightrightarrows M]$, does there exist a Lie groupoid $G$-extension $X_1\rightarrow Y_1\rightrightarrows M$, such that, the associated **band** is isomorphic, as principal $\text{Out}(G)$ bundles,  to the principal bundle $P\rightarrow M$?